# How to avoid antivirus to delete monero miner?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining

I have tried to download a lot of miners and all of them are deleted, I don't even know who is deleting them, if Windows antivirus or McAfee antivirus. I have tried to change configurations, turn them off, etc. but nothing seems to work, is there a way to download and use a miner easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you try to mine at work and your employers antivirus is blocking your miner? ;)

1) You could run the miner inside a virtual machine. With VMWare or VirtualBox. I would recommend to use Ubuntu Server.

2) Run the miner in the browser with [cryptonoter](https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter) or [deepminer](https://github.com/deepwn/deepMiner). That way you only have to open a website

3) If the antivirus is blocking the executable, then you could try using a [node.js miner](https://github.com/cazala/coin-hive)

Answer (score 3):

Try to set exceptions in the Anti-Virus software, which means to exclude certain directories and/or files to be excluded from scans.
It worked out for me for xmr-stak miner, which was detected as virus/trojan in MS Security Essentials.