# Why AVs reject miners?

Tags: security

I have been trying to install miners on my windows, but mostly detected as a threat by AVs.
Why are most of the miners blocked by Antivirus programs?
Is there any miner which has no problem with Antiviruses?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any AV software that doesn't detect miners.

If you want to know what you can do so that AV software doesn't detect a miner, take a look [at my answer here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/how-to-avoid-antivirus-to-delete-monero-miner/7611#7611)

Answer (score 1):

Miners are usually flagged by anti-viruses as people create malicious software to mine Crypto-Currencies on the owners computer without their knowledge, and your average user is unlikely to be mining Crypto-Currencies so all miners are flagged. 
This doesn't usually affect serious miners as they don't install unneeded software and if using Windows have whether it be a registry edit or other method have disabled Windows defender.